# Python convert HTML tags to proper entities

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

We have to convert html to proper text with entities. 
The html contains unsorted lists, paragraphs, breaks, sorted lists, etc...

What we need is something like this:

```
<p> Title <br /> Subtitle </p>
<ul>
    <li><b>list item 1</b></li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Some more text</p>
```

This should be properly converted to:

```
Title\n
Subtitle\n\n
&bull;List item 1\n
&bull;List item 2\n
Some more text
```

Bold, strong, italic, etc... can be ignored.

I have worked with regular expressions, BeautifulSoup and lxml. 
I have read a lot of articles on the internet among which Stackoverflow, but I can't find a proper solution.

I figured, if a browser is able to display this, it can also be parsed properly.

Comment: Yes, a browser can parse an HTML file thanks to a few thousand lines of code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have made a script so far containing a couple of regular expressions. But why reinvent the wheel if it already exists